# ms-access full text search with fuzzy logic

Tags: ms-access, full-text-search

In ms access I have been using soundex for possible matching options but now i want to use full text searching is there any code available for that eg: rose give letter to ram will possible match to ram got letter rose like fuzzy

Answer (score 0):

Access does not have a full text indexing option.

You could I suppose write your own routines, but that would take considerable work. As a result, best effort would be to migrate the data file to say a free edition of SQL server – the express editions do support text indexing, and thus allow searching of text by keywords, even when not in the same order as the text or memo column in question.

I suppose if you only searching say one column, and you willing to write VBA code to take the key words, and then loop each given keyword, and do a VBA “instr” command on the one column, then this could work, but it would be slow, and you would not have say use of SQL queries to do all the heavy lifting for you.

It is likely less work to send the data to a free edition of SQL server then it is to write such code. A migration of the data to SQL server will still allow you to use your existing application and VBA anyway.